# How to create a component for Android with Delphi xe5

Tags: android, delphi, components

I've tried to create a component for Android with RAD Delphi XE5.
I can create a component but not for the target platform Android.
On the Website of Embarcadero I can't find a tutorial or documentation about this Topic.
Is it possible. And when - how?

Michael

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/FireMonkey_Components_Guide

Comment: A better link (from the same docs) that goes step-by-step through creating a cross platform panel for Win/OSX/iOS/Android: [Creating a FireMonkey Component - Delphi](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Creating_a_FireMonkey_Component_%28Delphi%29).

Comment: Thank you Peter for the quick answer. I will try this.